# Разработайте программу которая находит кубы всех элементов исходной матрицы А

Tags: pascal

Дана матрица вещественного типа A(2,7). Разработайте программу которая находит кубы всех элементов исходной матрицы  А. Выведите на экран полученную матрицу
Ниже код, но почему то не выводит на экран исходную матрицу

```
program Project1;
const
  maxrow = 2;
  maxcol = 7;
var
  a: array[1..maxrow,1..maxcol] of real; { Переменная для хранения массива.}
  i,j: integer; { Вспомогательные переменные для организации циклов.}
 
begin
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    for j:= 1 to maxcol do
    begin
      write('Введите значение элемента [',i,',',j,']: ');
      Readln(a[i,j]);         { Ввод значений в двумерный массив.}
    end;
  writeln('Исходная матрица: ');
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    begin
      for j:= 1 to maxcol do
        write(a[i,j]:7:2);    { Вывод двумерного массива в консоль.}
      Writeln;
    end;
  writeln('Измененная матрица (каждый элемент возведен в куб): ');
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    begin
      for j:= 1 to maxcol do
        begin
          a[i,j]:= a[i,j]*a[i,j]*a[i,j]; { Вычисление куба элемента}
          end;
          Writeln;
    end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё выводит у меня...................... https://onlinegdb.com/SybS-d8a8

Теперь кубы тоже

```
program Project1;
const
  maxrow = 2;
  maxcol = 7;
var
  a: array[1..maxrow,1..maxcol] of real; { Переменная для хранения массива.}
  i,j: integer; { Вспомогательные переменные для организации циклов.}
 
begin
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    for j:= 1 to maxcol do
    begin
      write('Введите значение элемента [',i,',',j,']: ');
      Readln(a[i,j]);         { Ввод значений в двумерный массив.}
    end;
  writeln('Исходная матрица: ');
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    begin
      for j:= 1 to maxcol do
        write(a[i,j]:7:2);    { Вывод двумерного массива в консоль.}
      Writeln;
    end;
  writeln('Измененная матрица (каждый элемент возведен в куб): ');
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    begin
      for j:= 1 to maxcol do
        begin
          a[i,j]:= a[i,j]*a[i,j]*a[i,j]; { Вычисление куба элемента}
          write(a[i,j]:7:2);
        end;
   
        Writeln;
    end;
  Readln;
end.
```